# fromJS() is not respecting my normalized object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I have a normalized object of fields:

```
console.log(action.payload.entities)
```

[image]

I pass this through `fromJS()` but field 11 is appearing first in the `Map()` results here.

```
const normalizedMap = fromJS(action.payload.entities)
console.log(normalizedMap)
```

[image]

Why is formJS doing that and how can I keep my ordering of my normalized results.

Comment: Please embed your code in your question as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Turns fromJS() accepts a reviver function, and in their example they show how to apply an OrderedMap instead of Map which doesn't respect order.

Also, as of writing by default I was on 3.8.1 and I had to manually upgrade to 4.0.0-rc.2

https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS

```
const normalizedMap = fromJS(action.payload.entities, function (key, value {
    return isKeyed(value) ? value.toOrderedMap() : value.toList()
  })
```